# Using S3Hook to get the last modified date of S3 files

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

Is there a way to get the last modified date using S3Hook, not boto?

```
keys = s3.list_keys(bucket_name=Variable.get('s3_bucket'), prefix='FBK/billing/', delimiter="/")
```

This would be the next step, but I essentially want to find the latest modified date of all the S3files from `keys` so I can then compare it with the last successfully dag run so I think I would do this:

```
last_successful_dag_run_date = {{ prev_execution_date_success }}

for key_date in keys_last_modified_date:
   if key_date > last_successful_dag_run_date:
       "ingest to db"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acchieve this with the following code:

```
s3_bucket = s3_hook.get_bucket(bucket_name=Variable.get('s3_bucket'))
last_modified_attrs = [obj.last_modified for obj in s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='FBK/billing/')]
```

`get_bucket` will return a `boto3.S3.Bucket` object, from which you can access and filter the within contained S3Objects